# CMake/C++ project organization on github

Tags: c++, github, cmake

If I have a few projects, say A, B, C, that build on top each other.  For example, B and C depend on A.  And, C depends on B and A.  A has no dependancies.

I want to also make sure that people downloading a project dont have to worry about downloading the dependancies separately.  So if someone downloads B, A is automatically included with it.  It is OK if it contains duplicate code in each repository as long as that can be deduped if the downloader downloads all of them.

What is the best way to organize projects like this?  Thanks

Comment: You can use git submodules for this. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Is it a requirement that the projects are stored in separate repos?

Comment: @scy7he generally speaking you want that, it's safer to not go for other options .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) from git, this is the term for what you are looking for .